# Java swing - JLabels inside JList get random top padding

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jlist

I'm trying to make a JList. For some reason the JLabel of some random elements have a top padding like this:

[image: random top padding for some elements]

As you can see in the picture, the first, fourth, and seventh row all have a top padding in their first JLabel. One way I managed to eliminate this effect is by making the text in the JLabel only one line, but that doesn't solve the problem because I need it to contain multiple lines.

Code:

```
package maya.page;

import maya.Main;
import maya.object.Module;
import maya.object.Occurrence;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class StudentModulePanel extends JPanel {
    public StudentModulePanel(){
        DefaultListModel<Occurrence> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        listModel.addAll(Main.modules.get("WIX1002").getOccurrences());

        JList<Occurrence> list = new JList<>(listModel);
        list.setCellRenderer(new OccurrenceRenderer());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        add(scrollPane, c);

        setBackground(new Color(180, 230, 230));
    }
}

class OccurrenceRenderer extends OccurrencePanel implements ListCellRenderer<Occurrence>{
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Occurrence> list, Occurrence value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        setOccurrence(value);

        if(isSelected){
            setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        } else {
            setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
        }

        return this;
    }
}

class OccurrencePanel extends JPanel{
    Occurrence occurrence;

    JLabel moduleTitleLabel = new JLabel();
    JLabel occurrenceNumberLabel = new JLabel();
    JLabel activityLabel = new JLabel();
    JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel();
    JLabel tutorLabel = new JLabel();
    JLabel targetLabel = new JLabel();
    JLabel actualLabel = new JLabel();

    void setOccurrence(Occurrence occurrence){
        this.occurrence = occurrence;

        Module module = Main.modules.get(occurrence.getCode());

        moduleTitleLabel.setText(String.format("<html>%s - %s %s</html>", module.getCode(), module.getCode(), module.getTitle()));
        occurrenceNumberLabel.setText(Integer.toString(occurrence.getOccurrenceNumber()));
        activityLabel.setText(occurrence.getActivityString());
        timeLabel.setText(occurrence.getTime());
        tutorLabel.setText(String.format("<html>%s</html>", "TUTOR")); //occurrence.getTutor()));
        targetLabel.setText(Integer.toString(occurrence.getTargetStudents()));
        actualLabel.setText(Integer.toString(occurrence.getActualStudents()));
    }


    OccurrencePanel(){
        int height = 75;
        Dimension bigLabelSize = new Dimension(200, height);
        Dimension smallLabelSize = new Dimension(40, height);
        Dimension activityLabelSize = new Dimension(75, height);
        int padding = 10;
        EmptyBorder paddingBorder = new EmptyBorder(0, padding, 0, padding);

        moduleTitleLabel.setPreferredSize(bigLabelSize);
        moduleTitleLabel.setBorder(paddingBorder);

        occurrenceNumberLabel.setPreferredSize(smallLabelSize);
        occurrenceNumberLabel.setBorder(paddingBorder);

        activityLabel.setPreferredSize(activityLabelSize);
        activityLabel.setBorder(paddingBorder);

        timeLabel.setPreferredSize(bigLabelSize);
        timeLabel.setBorder(paddingBorder);

        tutorLabel.setPreferredSize(bigLabelSize);
        tutorLabel.setBorder(paddingBorder);

        targetLabel.setPreferredSize(smallLabelSize);
        targetLabel.setBorder(paddingBorder);

        targetLabel.setPreferredSize(smallLabelSize);
        actualLabel.setBorder(paddingBorder);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        add(moduleTitleLabel, c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        add(occurrenceNumberLabel, c);

        c.gridx = 2;
        add(activityLabel, c);

        c.gridx = 3;
        add(timeLabel, c);

        c.gridx = 4;
        add(tutorLabel, c);

        c.gridx = 5;
        add(targetLabel, c);

        c.gridx = 6;
        add(actualLabel, c);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use an JTable instead of JList, you would not need the JPanel with all the JLabels. And you would most likely not  need your own renderer.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can also read and debug your code. Please don't post all your classes here, but rather create a small example that demonstrates your problem.